# React Native: cancellable promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, cancellation

I have a piece of behavior scheduled for execution in the future. For example as an argument of *then* of a Promise. But due to some reasons I may want not to execute it and this decision is made in between of setting a behavior and executing it.

What is the most simple way of putting it into code?

**Update.** The task management is out-of-control, because it is defined by API. It returns a promise and there is no way of getting it cancelled as well as the underlying task.

The goal is to prevent a behavior defined for future execution from happening due to it may cause unwanted or obsolete changes to the data.

Comment: Promises are not cancellable. However, observables are. See https://medium.com/the-geeks-of-creately/cancelling-observables-rxjs-f4cf28c3b633 Note that cancelling something that is already started is quite a difficult task that often involves rolling back. For example, you can cancel an XHR made through observables, but it doesn't mean that the action will be undone, you may need to fire another XHR to undo that first action

Comment: And in case you do not want to use Observables, you can have a flag set. And the callback passed in `.then()` should first check the flag and then proceed

Comment: @AnandUndavia You can do that, but you are not cancelling the promise, right? Maybe the question is not well posed and assumes the answer should be a cancelable promise, but an extra parameter may do the job. Hard to tell when the OP doesn't explain their problem with code. Hand waving questions are less likely to get good answers

Comment: @JuanMendes Definitely it is hard to tell what is OP really asking for. That's why I added "in case you do not want to use Observables". OP would decide whether he has to cancel the task completely or he does not care about the tasks and just what happens afterwards

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you would like to cancel? The behavior itself (API call?) or whatever was supposed to happen after promise is resolved?

Comment: **whatever was supposed to happen after promise is resolved** -- API call is out-of-control for calling instance